# run.bat file executing multiple files

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have written a client server application in C# using Visual studio.
The application runs perfectly when I am running from Visual studio.

But when I am running the application from my .bat file, my server instances are getting closed and only
client is being shown.

Below is my bat file.
Could you please check if I am missing anything.

start/d "Client1\bin\Debug" Client1.exe

start/d "Server2\bin\Debug" Server2.exe

start/d "Server1\bin\Debug" Server1.exe

Comment: Your server application simply exists or crashes.

Comment: Do you have any more information? does it shows some errors?

Comment: Wrong syntax, should be `start "" /d "Client1\bin\Debug" Client1.exe` - the window title is compulsory, so you need to include at least empty one, `""`